# Dojo Memory setData won't set data

Tags: combobox, dojo

I have a Problem. I am writing a ComboBox on dojo and if the user is writing an option which is not yet in the store it will be added.

I have wrote a keyup Event and it will be triggered if the user hits RETURN or ENTER

```
if(pressed.keyCode == keys.ENTER){
                //var dtemp = dijit.byId("stateSelect").get("store");
                var MyMemory = new myownclass();
                var value = dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value');
                var isNew = true;
                var d = new Memory({data : []});
                for(var vi = 0; MyMemory.data[vi].name != "";vi++)
                {
                    d.put({name : MyMemory.data[vi].name, id : MyMemory.data[vi].id});
                }
                for(var index = 0; index < d.length ; index++)
                {
                    if(value == d[index].name)
                    {
                        //alert(value);
                        isNew = false;
                    }
                    //isNew = true;
                }
                if(isNew == true){
                    MyMemory.setdata(value);
                    //var newData = new myownclass();
                    d.put({name : value, id : vi});
                    //dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('store').reset();
                    dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('store').setData(d);

                }
            }
            if(pressed.keyCode == keys.F2){
                var MyMemory = new myownclass();
                var value = dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value');
                    MyMemory.deletedata(value);
                    //var temp = new myownclass();
                    //dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('store').remove(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('store').get('id'));

            }
```

The Problem is that it does not want to replace the old store with the new store d! Instead the ComboBox is completely empty :(

The **var d** has content inside
[image: Firebug Screen]

anyone who knows why it won't display the Options?

Thanks for Help

Comment: why do you set the data to store every time. instead you can use "add" and "remove" methods of the memory store, which is neat and sleek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using [`setData()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/store/Memory#1_9dojo_store_Memory_setData) incorrect. The `setData()` expects an array of objects to be inserted. However, you're using it to insert `d`, which is a store by itself. So, the correct way of setting the data would by by using:

```js
dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('store').setData(d.query());
```

Because if you use the [`query()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/store/Memory#1_9dojo_store_Memory_query) function without parameters, it will return all objects inside the store (as an array).

**However**, you could also directly change the store of the combobox by using:

```js
dijit.byId('stateSelect').set('store', d);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu8AT/)'s a simple example using the store setter.

Comment: The function Memory.remove(1) <-- Removes the second object or do it remove the item with the id=1 ?

Comment: The best source to get this information is by looking at the API docs, which says `"Deletes an object by its identity"`. So it's the item with `id=1`.